# PDF Digital Signatures in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, pdf-generation, digital-signature, playframework-1.x

I'm using play framework(v1.2) and using PDF Module in Play framework to render PDF. I would like to implement digital signature in PDF using renderPDF() method.

I gone through the options and I couldn't find any thing related signature.

From the Google search play uses YaHP converter to convert HTML to PDF and YaHP have an option to give signature related properties.

Do we have options to implement it using PDF module in Play?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, iText is part of the Play Framework, although it may be an obsolete version. In any case: if you need to add digital signatures in PDF, iText is the way to go: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

Comment: I think YaHP internally uses iText, Let me go thru this PDF whether it helps me or not. Thanks !!!

Comment: Did some research and answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done in Play framework by just configuring below properties in application.conf

```
yahp.USE_PDF_SIGNING=true
yahp.PDF_SIGNING_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE=<keystore file>
yahp.PDF_SIGNING_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=<password>
yahp.PDF_SIGNING_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD=<password>
```

Play will read this properties while PDF generation.